# Can non-virtual member functions use template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I've been wondering, can a *non-virtual* member function use template parameters? IOW, should a function using template parameters be virtual?

Example:

```
template<int N>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass() {}

    // Can this function be non-virtual?
    int getValue() {
      return N;
    }

}
```

If I understand correctly, the compiler will basically generate one class for each template parameter *value*. In the above example, there would be multiple classes (one for each value of N) implicitly generated deriving from `SomeClass`. Hence, in my understanding, `getValue()` would need to be dispatched dynamically (to different instances of the function) depending on the actual (runtime) type.

I know that the compiler does not enforce those functions to be virtual, but can it do some magic or would I really have to make the function virtual to have the right instance be called via e.g. pointer?

Comment: Different instantiations of `SomeClass` are not related by any kind of inheritance. They are just different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence, in my understanding, getValue() would need to be dispatched dynamically (to different instances of the function) depending on the actual (runtime) type.

A type which is encoded right there in the object declaration:

```
SomeClass<0> s;
s.getValue();
```

The compiler will dispatch to `SomeClass<0>::getValue`. It doesn't have to be dispatched at runtime, it's all available statically to the type system. Once a class template is instantiated to create a *class*, it's just like any other class. If you were to write:

```
SomeOtherClass c; // Not a template
s.doSomething();
```

The compiler knows it should dispatch to `SomeOtherClass::doSomething` just the same.

Comment: `SomeClass *ptr = new SomeClass<99>` is thus not valid?

Comment: @JimmyB - There is no common `SomeClass` base class. C++ templates are quite dissimilar to Java's generics. They are instructions for generating classes. Other than coming from the same template, those classes have nothing in common.